# String.charCodeAt undefined?

Tags: javascript, safari

I get this error in the javascript debug panel when trying to call String.charCodeAt('9') in Safari 3.

> TypeError: Result of expression 'String.charCodeAt' [undefined] is not a function.

When I try to do stringInstance.charCodeAt('9') instead, I get NaN.  Am I doing something wrong?  I'd just like to get the char code for some characters to match against keypresses.  String.charCodeAt('9') returns 57 (as expected) on Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

I think the proper way is:

"9".charCodeAt(0)

or stringInstace.charCodeAt(charIndex) where charIndex is an integer

Comment: can you please tell me in detail in your answer and question i didn't find any difference ??

Comment: `_string_.charCodeAt(_index_)` takes an index as its argument and looks up the Unicode UTF-16 code point of the character from _string_ with the given _index_. The argument is the index of the character within the string to look up, not the character itself.